# Getting error while loading UMD module which imports highcharts (“Highcharts JS v5.0.14”) from main module (angular4)

Tags: angular, highcharts, gulp, umd

Getting error while loading UMD module which imports highcharts (“Highcharts JS v5.0.14”) from main module (angular4).
Please find the attached sample application code with issue. The application details,

1. Created the “amat-apf-analytics” UMD module (“amat-apf-analytics.umd.js”) to be utilized across different application. 
   “/test/src” folder module will be converted as a single “amat-apf-analytics.umd.js” bundle by using gulp (“test/gulpfile.js” – gulp configuration file).
   This “amat-apf-analytics.umd.js” is imported highcharts into it. Highcharts is included as external module in “gulpfile.js” since it is external to the amat-apf-analytics UMD bundle.
2. Highcharts is configured in “system.config.js”. It will get loaded before loading amat-apf-analytics module.
3. Main application is located in /test/APF folder and it will load highcharts and amat-apf-analytics from “/test/APF node_modules/”.
4. While loading getting the below error,

[image]